# How to set dispose action to Observable?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

I know how to create an observable and assign a disposing action:

```
Observable.Create(o =>
{
    // o.OnNext etc.
    return Disposable.Create(() => { /* ... */ });
});
```

But now I produced an observable from query syntax:

```
var observable = from x in otherObservable
                 select x;
```

How to assign a disposing action to such query?

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, you want to "chain" or "listen" whenever the subscription is disposed. One way to do this is to use the `Finally` operator of `IObservable<T>`, as such:

```
var ob = from x in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            select x;

// Use Finally to create an intermediate IObservable
var disposeSub = ob.Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("disposed"));

// Subscribe to the intermediate observable instead the original one
var yourSub    = disposeSub.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

// Wait for some numbers to print
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));

// "disposed" will be written on the console at this point
yourSub.Dispose();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: You can even return the `.Finally( () => { ... }` directly from your LINQ query in the first line, if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should clarify your question. It's not entirely clear what you mean by "disposing action".

Calling an action using `Observable.Finally` has been suggested, but this action would run when the first of the following conditions is met:

- The Observable sends `OnCompleted()`
- The Observable sends `OnError()`
- The subscription handle is disposed.

i.e. You can't guarantee that the action will be executed precisely when you call `Dispose` on the subscription handle; it may have already been run - but calling `Dispose` ensures it will have been invoked before the call to `Dispose` returns.

This may be what you need - but taking you at your word, you *only* want the action to run in the last of these cases - on dispose of the handle, then you would need to attach the action to the subscription handle itself, ie:

```
var otherDisposable = /* your observable */;

Action disposingAction = () => Console.WriteLine("I am disposed!");

var subscription = otherDisposable.Subscribe(/* set your handlers here */);

var disposable = new CompositeDisposable(
    subscription,
    Disposable.Create(disposingAction));

/* The disposingAction is *only* run when this is called */
disposable.Dispose();
```

I can't think what scenario would require this though, I wonder if `Observable.Finally`, as suggested by Carlos, is a better fit!

Comment: I think it's just another way to go about it, James. It would be hard, nevertheless to ensure that his "Dispose"  is ALWAYS called. I also think your suggestion is more straightforward, using `CompositeDisposable`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't dispose an observable. You dispose a subscription to an observable.

Example:

```
var observable = from x in otherObservable
             select x;

var sub = observable.Subscribe(DoStuff);
sub.Dispose();
```

Comment: My question is: How to invoke an action that will be invoked when I call _sub.Dispose();_ within that disposing method.

Comment: What do you mean? You can put whatever action you want where you have `/* ... */`